# How Nuxt SSG generate with database

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

Im a bit confused on how SSG works with a database. Let's say I have a post page that's pulling the data from an api. Something like this:

**Post page**

```
<template>
  <div v-for="post in posts">
    {{post}}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    const {data:posts} = useFetch('some_api_url')
</script>
```

According to my understanding, SSG means that the page is rendered during build time with the content.

With that logic, does it mean that when we run **npm run generate**, Nuxt will make the api request first to get the posts from the api, and render it inside the template before building the page as a static page.

If this is true, does it mean that:

1. The useFetch method wont be triggered when the user visit the page on our website (meaning no api calls to fetch the posts)
2. Before building, we have to make sure we are connected to our LIVE api not LOCAL api to make sure the content is similar to production.

Comment: SSG, means that it will takes a "picture" of your data at a given moment, if the database data changes, you need to generate it again. 1. the hook will be triggered, build the app locally to see how it works more in details. 2. this is not something directly related to nuxt but you should indeed have some env variables for both local and production environments, so that the context switch is made automatically based on where your app is running/built (the build does not need to be done locally, can be done directly in the CI of the hosting platform).